# What can someone with read access to .git folder do?

Tags: git

I am new to git and having setup a self hosted repo on a live site, I am not sure what someone with read access to .git folder (in the root) can potentially do. Is it safe to have it set to `755`?

My project website.com is in the public_html root folder. At this point all I want to know is whether or not someone with advanced knowledge of git can potentially clone my repo? I haven't taken any measures to make this repo private.

Comment: You don't have a `.git` in the `/` root, you have it at top of your project tree.

Comment: My project website.com is in the public_html root folder. At this point all I want to know is whether or not someone with advanced knowledge of git can potentially clone my repo? I haven't taken any measures to make this repo private.

Comment: You should configure your web sever to deny HTTP access to `.git` or anything under it.

Comment: Yes, someone can definitely clone your repo from `.git`. (That’s how all clones work.) Don’t copy it into your `public_html` to begin with.

Comment: Can I block http access to .git without blocking my git client (sourcetree) that I use to push my commits?

Comment: That setup doesn’t really sound like it makes sense. You can’t push files into a working directory without some kind of hook as far as I know – and if you have a hook, you can just point it anywhere.

Comment: I have got a local repo where I am doing all of my work. The remote repo was initialised as a bare repo and I only push master to it when something has to go live.

Comment: So why does it need to be in `public_html`? Put it somewhere else…

Comment: I'll change my setup, if you can post a short answer, I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While no one can write to it, it does fully expose your source code. Which means someone can study anything you write and know exactly where potential vulnerabilities lie.

See here for more information: https://en.internetwache.org/dont-publicly-expose-git-or-how-we-downloaded-your-websites-sourcecode-an-analysis-of-alexas-1m-28-07-2015/

Comment: I stumbled upon this link today while doing a bit of research.

Answer (score 1):

**GIT Read, Write**

- Guest - No access to code
- Reporter - Read the repository
- Developer - Read/Write to the repository
- Master - Read/Write to the repository + partial administrative
  capabilities
- Owner - Read/Write to the repository + full administrative
  capabilities

The permissions are named to reflect their purpose. A user with the lowest private permission Guest is only able to make use of the issues in a project and does not have read access to the code; a guest of the project.

The Reporter permission has the same abilities, but also has read access to the code, meaning they can fork the project. This is ideal for those that you do not want to be pushing to your repository, but still want to give access to the code and give the option to fork off.

As the name implies, developers on a project should get the role Developer. Any developer has write permission to the repository, meaning they can branch off, work in and push their own branch back to the repository.

By defining permission on a read/write basis with clear names, it quickly becomes clear which permission level should be used to secure a project. However, they do not solve the issues with modifying history, nor do they help with collaboration: anyone can (force) push to any branch (such as the master branch).